# c++ Can I Initialize a variable of type float with a double?

Tags: c++, types, floating-point, initialization, double

Haven't really been able to find much about this. Though compiler doesn't seem to complain when I initialize a variable of type `float` with a `double` e.g.

```
double a = 1.0;
float b = a;
```

It works fine, but I am still curious if it is OK to do this, and/or is it safe?

(I am on a 32 bit system running windows)

Comment: @coddding What definition of "safe" should be assumed in answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of the created variable is different. "float = 4 bytes" and "double = 8 bytes". Hence, what is important here is the range of values are different for both types. If you use small values as 1.0 it should not effect the workflow.

Answer (score 2):

> **4.8 Floating point conversions**
>
> <sup>1</sup> A prvalue of floating point type can be converted to a prvalue of another floating point type. If the
> source value can be exactly represented in the destination type, the result of the conversion is that exact
> representation. If the source value is between two adjacent destination values, the result of the conversion
> is an implementation-defined choice of either of those values. Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: The last clause (undefined behavior) applies to source values outside the representable range of the target format. So it is incorrect to state that "generally" undefined behavior results. For the specific case of `double` to `float` conversion, the first clause applies to source data like `5.0`; the second clause applies to source data like `3.14159265358979323`; the last clause applies to source data like `1e308`.

Comment: Generally speaking, it's **not** undefined behavior.

Comment: @njuffa The question is "_Can I Initialize a variable of type float with a double?_". `1` is just a sample value, `1e308` could be another sample. I'm not a native speaker, but what I mean is "_in general case, i.e. without assumptions about representations of `float` and `double` and without assumptions of concrete values, it is UB_".

Comment: @PeteBecker Do you mean it is incorrect to say that "_generally speaking `float x = any_double()` is UB_"? (I intended to answer the general question about double-to-float assignment, not restricted to particular values.)

Comment: @AlexD - if you choose a `double` value at random, there's a good chance that it won't be convertible to `float`. But if you choose `double` values that people typically want to convert to `float` (as in the initialization examples here), the conversion is valid and well defined. "Generally speaking" isn't helpful here.

Comment: @PeteBecker I think it is a language issue. I [meant](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/generally) "_in disregard of specific instances and with regard to an overall picture_") not "_usually_". Anyway, I removed the sentence as people find it confusing.

Answer (score 1):

As the name implies, a double has 2x the precision of float[1]. In general a double has 15 decimal digits of precision, while float has 7.

Here's how the number of digits are calculated:

```
double has 52 mantissa bits + 1 hidden bit: log(253)÷log(10) = 15.95 digits

float has 23 mantissa bits + 1 hidden bit: log(224)÷log(10) = 7.22 digits
```

Maybe you gonna lose precision doing it.